# To get the multi dimention array values in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, associative-array

I have a multi-dimension array in php like this

```
$shop = array( 
               array("name","point","number"),
               array('Ranjit', 1.25 , 15),
               array('Pitabas', 0.75 , 25),
               array('Khela', 1.15 , 7) 
             );
```

Now I have to show the output like this

```
name-> ranjit
Point-> 1.25
number->15
name->Pitabas
Point->0.75
number->25
name->Khela
Point->1.15
number->7
```

I am trying for loop, but I could get the result in nested forloop. Please help me to get the answer.

Comment: Please share the loop you tried. Perhaps there is a simple error that can be fixed. And it shows people that you genuinely tried.

Comment: I posted an answer and will undelete it once I know you at least tried first.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but when people ask me 'plz' because it's shorter than 'please', I just want to tell them 'no' because it's shorter than 'yes'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution:

```
$headings = array_shift($shop);

foreach ($shop as $item) {
  foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
    echo $headings[$key], '=>', $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. I couldn't think of `array_shift()`, so I used the "get first row, skip first row in loop" approach.

Answer (score 0):

You know the first row will be the titles, so store them separately:

```
$titles = $shop[0];
```

That will give you

```
$titles = array('name', 'point', 'number');
```

Then loop through your array:

```
foreach ($shop as $index => $row) {
    if ($index == 0) 
        continue;

    foreach($row as $column => $item) {
        echo $titles[$column] . " -&gt; " . $item . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an odd construction for your loop.  You should use foreach($shop as $i=>$row) - it's a little easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple loop: Observe that we skip the first element of the outer array, which is deemed to contain the headers:

```
for ($i = 1; $i != count($shop); ++$i)
{
    print $shop[0][0] . ": ". $shop[$i][0] . "\n";
    print $shop[0][1] . ": ". $shop[$i][1] . "\n";
    print $shop[0][2] . ": ". $shop[$i][2] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give the desired output:

```
for($x = 1, $lim = sizeof($shop); $x < $lim; $x++)
{
    echo $shop[0][0]."->".$shop[$x][0]."<br>";
    echo $shop[0][1]."->".$shop[$x][1]."<br>";
    echo $shop[0][2]."->".$shop[$x][2]."<br>";
}
```